# How to choose limits of integration when calculating the volume of a tridimensional object.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, surfaces

I am trying to compute the volume of the figure limited by these surfaces:
$$z=xy$$
$$x+y+z=1$$
$$z=0$$

**My attempt:**

Using the first two equations I get $y=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$, which is, I think, the projection in the $XY$ plane of the intersection between these two surfaces (am I right?). Taking this into account I clonclude that the volume ($V$) is:
$$V=\int_0^1\int_0^{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}xydydx+\int_0^1\int_{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}^{1-x}(1-x-y)dydx$$

**My question:**

I have a few doubts about this exercise. **Firstly**, I would like to know if what I have done is correct (I am concerned that the part about the projection may be wrong).

**Secondly**, is there another way to solve this exercise in which the integrals are a bit easier? (I think I know how to solve the ones I get, but it takes me some time to do them by hand), maybe I could have used triple integrals?

And finally, **my main problem** with this kind of exercise is that I do not manage to imagine the figure I am working with (which is what I do when I compute areas of shapes in two dimensions). When it is just spheres, planes and cylinders, I more or less manage to approach the problem successfully. However, when surfaces like $z=xy$ appear I start to have problems choosing the limits of integration. In this particular problem I could only come up with my solution (I am not even sure it is correct) because I used Geogebra to see what the figure looked like. Could someone suggest a way to approach this kind of problem? Is there a way to solve it without having to know what the figure looks like? Or should I learn more about quadrics in order to be able to picture them in my head?

Any help will be very useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you should be happy with yourself that you saw that the integral had to broken into two pieces, many people would have missed that. In general you have to improve your visualization skills, otherwise you will not be able to set up your integrals correctly (manipulating inequalities can only carry you so far). This is a two way street, however, as your instructors will not give you questions which they themselves cannot visualize.

Comment: FWIW, I believe your bounds are correct.

Comment: It is possible to make this one integral - use the substitution $u = x+y$ and $v = x-y$ then the integral becomes one integral by doing the $u$ integral first.